# Trouble creating a package for my PPA

Tags: ppa, package-management, python

So I tried following the steps [here](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/PackagingGuide/Complete) to create a package to upload to my PPA. I ran `dh_make` and edited the files. However, when my package gets generated by `debuild`, none of the programs files show up in the package.

Here is the output of `debuild`:

> ...
>   dpkg-source: warning: ignoring deletion of directory share
>   dpkg-source: warning: ignoring deletion of directory share/pixmaps
>   ...

Here is what the filesystem looks like:

> build_root
>       - *packagename*_1.2.orig.tar.gz
>       - *packagename*-1.2
>            - debian
>                - control
>                ...

The application is written in Python, if that means anything.

---

**Edit:**

Here is what the `packagename_1.2.orig.tar.gz` looks like:

> *packagename*-1.2
>        - src
>            - somefile.py
>            - someotherfilefile.py
>        - images
>            - test.png

---

Unfortunately, I'm still struggling...

Here is my `debian/rules` file:

```
#!/usr/bin/make -f
# -*- makefile -*-

# Uncomment this to turn on verbose mode.
#export DH_VERBOSE=1

%:
    dh  $@

override_dh_auto_build:

override_dh_auto_install:
```

...and here is my `package.install` file:

> src/myapp.server /usr/lib/bonobo/servers
>   src/myapp /usr/lib/myapp
>   images/test.png /usr/share/test

Comment: Are you using the CDBS or debhelper? Personally, I prefer debhelper. You can see the difference here: https://wiki.ubuntu.com/PackagingGuide/Python

Comment: @odd: I am using debhelper.

Comment: Does the package use distutils or something else for installation?

Comment: @Ressu: No. The package consists of a couple Python scripts and 5 PNGs. That's basically it. Could the format of the package-1.2.orig.tar.gz be a problem?

Comment: @Ressu: I added that information to the question.

Comment: Yup, that would be the problem.. The solution Umang offered should be sufficient.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You don't seem to use any build system, I think that's why you're not getting any files in your package. Have you tried looking at [changing your `debian/rules` file](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/PackagingGuide/Python#A%20sophisticated%20rules%20files)?

It should be pretty easy to do if you simply put a `mypackage.install` file in `debian/` and use the format specified in `man dh_install`. With appropriate substitutions, that file could look like this:

```
src/somefile.py usr/share/mypackage/
src/someotherfile.py usr/share/mypackage
bin/myexecutable usr/bin
image/test.png usr/share/icons/some/icon/dir/
```

If you do use a build system, override the `dh_auto_*` targets as explain in the link above  ([Python Packaging Guide](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/PackagingGuide/Python)) so that you're installing only these files and the build system (e.g `distutils`) doesn't interfere with files in your package.

Comment: If this doesn't help, please post your `rules` file, and list all the files in your `debian/` dir.

Comment: @Umang: Thanks for the detailed advice... I didn't touch the `rules` file - I left it unmodified. Would that be the problem?

Comment: Did you try making a `mypackage.install` file inside `debian/`? If you still got a problem, try the `override_dh_auto_*` (as explained in the Python Packaging Guide)

Comment: @umang: I posted the contents above. Still can't get it working.

Comment: @umang: Never mind. I fixed it. Thanks for your help!

Comment: Don't know whether this is what you did, but in `foo.install` you should start the second address with a forward slash. i.e. use `usr/share/foo` instead of `/usr/share/foo`. Glad I could help!