# Setting up a build system for Python app

Tags: python, application-development

In trying to sort out [this](https://askubuntu.com/questions/613/trouble-creating-a-package-for-my-ppa) issue, I have run into the following problem.

I have a Python script that gets installed to `/usr/lib/`. But I need to get this script into a build system so that I can get it working with my package.

Any help would be appreciated. Although I've worked a bit with Makefiles when writing C++ applications before, I've never created any kind of Makefile for Python files (nor do I even know where to start).

How would I go about setting up a build system for my app?

Comment: Python, Makefiles, and build systems belong on Stack Overflow. Two doors down, big statue of Jon Skeet out front. Can't miss it. :)

Comment: I disagree. If he's having trouble packaging an app for Ubuntu, I don't see that it's out of place here.

Comment: @mac9416: Nothing about his question asks anything remotely specific to Ubuntu, indicates he's having a problem with Ubuntu, indicates a desire to build a native Ubuntu package, or is any way related to Ubuntu. He's non-specifically asking about build systems for Python, very much an SO subject.

Comment: I can see your point that there's probably a _better_ place for this question (SO), but I don't think it's completely out of place here. I'll cut George some slack on this one.

Comment: I would agree except this deals exclusively with packaging for Ubuntu.

Comment: What's a "build system"? What's "working"? Your question is extremely unclear and general.

Comment: @Evan: A build system - like a Makefile, or scons, etc.

Comment: The other question is Ubuntu-specific.  Setting up a distro/OS-agnostic build system is not.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Well, like I explained on the other question, you don't need a build system and in that particular case, may be better off without one.

However, the most standard one is [distutils](http://docs.python.org/release/2.6.5/library/distutils.html). Just provide the metadata (i.e. name, description, etc) and a list of (python) packages, modules and scripts (all of them are optional) and it's done.

Finally, if you'd like to generate a debian package out of your project, then you can very easily do that by using `python-stdeb` (uses `dh7`, which I like better) or `python-mkdebian` (uses `cdbs`). There are many more differences between these tools, but I'll let you discover them yourself. Just note that both require using distutils. (`python-mkdebian` is part of the `python-distutils-extra` package in Ubuntu, I haven't used `-extra` much, but you can try that as well if you'd like)

Comment: Sorry, I misunderstood what you were saying in your other answer. Oh well. It's probably a good idea to learn distutils anyway.

Comment: Yes, learn distutils anyway! It won't take you more than a few minutes, I should imagine.

Comment: Well the problem is that distutils expects the files to have a .py extension - which mine does not.

Comment: For modules, yes. For packages, an `__init__.py` file and for scripts no extention. Just list it out as `scripts=['foo', 'bar'],`.

Answer (score 0):

[Scons](http://www.scons.org/) is a build system which uses Python as it's language (I generally prefer it over makefiles for any project), I think it should be capable of what you want to do.

It has a very good [User Guide](http://www.scons.org/doc/production/HTML/scons-user/index.html).

Comment: Oh no! I **can't stand** scons. I got stuck using a project that used scons. I just ended up writing a Makefile for it.

Answer (score 0):

Umang has the right answer, though perhaps not in as much detail as you might seem to need as a complete beginner.

For a Python program, you need to start by creating a `setup.py` file. The bulk of the file will be a call to `distutils.core.setup` - this is discussed in detail in [part 2 of the distutils documentation](http://docs.python.org/release/2.6.5/distutils/setupscript.html).

All other packaging systems for Python (such as py2exe, setuptools, or Distribute) build on top of the `distutils` package, usually by extending `setup()` in some way (with additional parameters or commands).

Before converting this into an Ubuntu package, you can test the setup script by running `sudo setup.py install`. It should install the files into their expected locations; if it doesn't you may need to check your configuration. In particular, sections 2.5 (scripts) and 2.6 (package data) of the `distutils` documentation probably apply to your situation.

Once that's done, you can then look at layering on the Ubuntu packaging according to the [Ubuntu Packaging Guide for Python](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/PackagingGuide/Python). The `python-stdeb` and `python-mkdebian` tools suggested by Umang simplify the generation of the various files required for Ubuntu packaging.

Comment: If you'd like a bit more info, you should know about the `distutils` [deviation from Python upstream](http://wiki.debian.org/Python#Deviationsfromupstream). Especially about `/usr/local/` instead of `/usr/`

Answer (score 0):

Make sure to check out:

http://pypi.python.org/pypi/modern-package-template/1.0
For a good default package layout including a starter setup.py file

http://pypi.python.org/pypi/virtualenv
For blocking off your dev environment from the rest of your system. Running something like

python setup.py develop

Will build/setup your command into your virtualenv so you can test it out.